# Google Adwords script to get info per month over last X years

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm looking for something like this script:
[Account summary report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/account-summary)

But with the addition of a breakdown per campaign.
Does anyone know of a good script library or how to modify this script to give per campaign results?

Answer (score 1):

Are you at all familiar with Javascript / AdWords Scripts? if so, please paste what you've tried, and we'll try and help. If not, consider visiting AdWords scripts' forum, or even paying a freelancer $20 to get this done

Comment: Freelancer sounds like a good idea for me at this point! I'll revisit this soon, thanks.